# Has gradle something like SBT ~ (tilde)?

Tags: gradle

In SBT there is option to run it in a loop, checking if sources changed and running specified action every time it happens.

E.g. when you run `sbt ~test` it runs tests, and then waits for sources to change. If some source file changes, it runs tests again. Then again it waits for sources to change, etc...

Is there such option in Gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet (as of 2.0), but it's a planned feature.

Comment: Is it planned for a concrete release or only in a "may have" fashion?

Comment: Would be nice if this question could get an update, now that ~7 years have passed, and Gradle's major version is just as large ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash

ARGS="$*"
while [[ ! -z "$1" ]]; do
    TASK=$1
    shift
    case "$TASK" in
        compile|compileJava|compileScala)
            MONITOR_DIR=src/main
            break
            ;;
        test|compileTestJava|compileTestScala)
            MONITOR_DIR=src/test
            break
            ;;
        build)
            MONITOR_DIR=src
            break
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
    esac
done
if [[ -z "$MONITOR_DIR" ]]; then
    echo "Error: could not detect a supported gradle task on the command line"
    exit 1
fi

if [[ "$(uname -s)" == "Darwin" ]]; then
    MD5=md5
else
    MD5=md5sum
fi

LAST=""
while [[ true ]]; do
    CURRENT="$(find $MONITOR_DIR -type f -exec $MD5 {} \;)"
    if [[ "$LAST" != "$CURRENT" ]]; then
        if [[ ! -z "$LAST" ]]; then
            echo "Change detected in $MONITOR_DIR => gradle $ARGS"
            echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
        fi
        LAST="$CURRENT"
        gradle $ARGS
        echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
        echo "Monitoring $MONITOR_DIR for changes..."
    fi
    sleep 2
done
```